# Absent Code attribute in method with Mockito and MockMvc

Tags: java, mocking, spring-restcontroller, mockmvc, springmockito

```
public class ExampleRestControllerTest {

     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Mock
     private MyService myService;

     @InjectMocks
     private MyRestController myRestController;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        StandaloneMockMvcBuilder setup =    MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myService);
        mockMvc = setup.build();
}
```

When `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myService);` is executed I have returned this stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:75)
at it.my.test.main.MyServiceRestControllerTest.setUp(MyServiceRestControllerTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

What may be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace and/or indicate which line of your code triggers this exception?

Comment: can you show where fattureResource is instantiated?

Comment: standaloneSetup() throw the exception

Comment: myService is a mock

Answer (score 0):

`standaloneSetup()` takes your controller. Maybe the following example can help you:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class IndexControllerTest {

    private IndexController classUnderTest;

    @Mock
    private IndexService mockedService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        classUnderTest = new IndexController(mockedService);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockMvc() throws Exception{
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(classUnderTest).build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("index"));

    }
}
```